# jquery: validate if element is empty before applying effect... is it necessary?

Tags: jquery

in jQuery, is it necessary to check if the variable contains something or jQuery does it by itself... let me explain with an example:

```
var image = $(placeholder).children('img');


// if placeholder contains image, hide it!
if (image.length) {
   alert('found one, hide it!');
   $(image).fadeOut(400);
}

... more code here...
```

i've realize that just writing the following works the same...

```
var image = $(placeholder).children('img');
$(image).fadeOut(400);
```

i mean, is it good practice to do a check first or let jquery handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong- when you do `$(image).fadeOut(400)`, the `fadeOut()` function is actually run against all the elements returned by `$(image)` (note that `$(image)` returns array of elements). So if `$(image)` returns empty array, the `fadeOut(400)` will be run against 0 element, so nothing will happen.

To answer your question, no you do not need to have the `if()` to check for the length, jQuery will do it for you. In my opinion, checking the length is just redundant and hurts performance, so I won't say it's a good practice.